# Header file about 'directed graphs' gives a Segmentation Fault

Tags: c++, stl, codeblocks, directed-graph

I use Code::Blocks and am trying to implement a header file that has 'graph' related methods like creating an adjacency list and printing them. But unfortunately, it gives a segmentation fault.

I use 'Vector of vectors' for my adjacency lists. Now weirdly Code::Blocks doesn't give any warnings or errors when I compile my code(nor does it work) but another compiler gives a segmentation fault.

(P.S. I know I should only prototype methods in my header file and use a separate source file to write them out but it's not working for some reason. Please bear with me)

Meat of my header file: (omitted the includes and namespace to be concise)

```
struct Edge{
    int src,dest;
};

class Graph{
    public:
        vector<vector<int>> adjList;
        int V,E;
        Graph(int,int);
        void dirGraph(vector<Edge> edges);
        void printGraph();
};

Graph::Graph(int V,int E)
{
    this->V = V;
    this->E = E;
}

void Graph::dirGraph(vector<Edge> edges)
{
    adjList.resize(V);
    for(auto edge:edges){
        adjList[edge.src].push_back(edge.dest);
    }
}

void Graph::printGraph(){
    for(int i=0 ; i<V ; ++i){
        cout << i;
        for(auto x:adjList[i]){
            cout << " -> " << x;
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Main File:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include "Graph.h"

using namespace std;

int main(){
    vector<Edge> edges =
    {
      {0,1},{1,2},{2,0},{2,1},{3,2},{4,5},{5,4}
    };
    Graph g1(5,7);
    g1.dirGraph(edges);
    g1.printGraph();
    return 0;
}
```

It should print the directed graph but it does nothing. (Code::Blocks gives 0 warnings and 0 errors. A separate online compiler gave the seg fault. But the  code doesn't work)

Edit: Someone asked for the includes, here they are:

```
#ifndef GRAPH_H_INCLUDED
#define GRAPH_H_INCLUDED
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

//my header file code

#endif
```

Comment: What did you observe when running your code in debug mode and stepping through line by line? Where exactly doe the exception occur?

Comment: `adjList` is too small.

Comment: Concise is not helpful when it means that anyone that wants to run your code has to imagine the parts you left out. Please make a [mcve].

Comment: *but another compiler gives a segmentation fault* -- Do this instead: `adjList.at(edge.src).push_back(edge.dest);` -- Now do you get a `std::out_of_range` exception thrown, regardless of the compiler you're using?

Comment: Yes! code::blocks terminates the program after the out of range exception is thrown.

Comment: This means that `edge.src` is out-of-bounds of the vector.  You need to review your code and make changes so that this doesn't occur.